# SharePoint 2013 Ribbon Missing Troubleshoot?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, ribbon

We applied client's customized master page, then the ribbon is missing some icon.
Not sure if it's resolution issue, how should I troubleshoot it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Number of things you can try here.  Revert back to OOTB master page. If it fixes the issue, then obviously the problem is on the new master page.

I don't think the problem is resolution.  It could be the resolution of the picture, but it looks like all the buttons are disabled.  If you are running in a regular IE window and the user has full access to the object you are accessing (list, list item, etc) then you may have done something to the security trimming.  My suggestion now is to determine if any javascript was added that disabled sections (CSS Classes) within the new page.  Also run the new page with your developer tools running and see if there is any code error out as it could have affected the security trimming as well.

Security Trimming is the hiding, disabling of data or controls within SharePoint based on the user's defined access.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I revert back to Seattle then the issues are fixed. I will try to see if any css class causes this issue, thanks!